# Is it possible to use MassTransit 3 with Azure Service Bus without Manage permission policy?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I spent some days testing **MassTransit 3.1.2** to see if we can use it with **Azure Service Bus** in our applications.

I made a sample with two console applications using  MassTransit.AzureServiceBus (3.1.2) : one publisher and one suscriber.

It works well. When I start the applications, the entities (queues, topic, subscriptions) are created automatically on my namespace on Azure.
That's nice when you are testing thing but in production, I don't want the application to be allowed to create entities. We want to create them upfront.

To try that, I thought It was a good idea to connect to the bus using SAS  policy with **"Send"** or **"Listen"** permissions only (before I was using a namespace policy with **"Manage"** permission).

Now I'm struggling on this point, I can't get it to work, I'm always getting  401 errors **Manage claim is required for this operation** if I don't use a policy with "Manage" permissions.
I tried setting the policy on the namespace or the entities directly without success.

After that I analyzed the stack trace exception (useless part omitted with [...]) :

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (401) Non autorisé. Manage claim is required for this operation. TrackingId:2ca420e3-aac6-467c-bacb-6e051dbc3e39_G47,TimeStamp:1/29/2016 11:20:41 PM ---> System.Net.WebException: Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (401) Non autorisé.
   à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__3c(GetAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---

Server stack trace:

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.EndGet[TEntityDescription](IAsyncResult asyncResult, String[]& resourceNames)
   à Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.EndGetQueue(IAsyncResult result)
   à System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
[...]
   à MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.NamespaceManagerExtensions.<CreateQueueSafeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
[...]
   à MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Pipeline.PrepareReceiveQueueFilter.<Send>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
[...]
   à MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusReceiveTransport.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<Receiver>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
[...]
   à MassTransit.Internals.Extensions.TaskExtensions.<WithCancellation>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception 
[...]
   à MassTransit.MassTransitBus.<StartAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à MassTransit.MassTransitBus.<StartAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   à MassTransit.Util.TaskUtil.Await[T](Func`1 taskFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   à MassTransit.MassTransitBus.MassTransit.IBusControl.Start()
```

I found out that the line with **MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.NamespaceManagerExtensions.CreateQueueSafeAsync** to be really interesting because I was able to look at the MassTransit source code to see what it was doing. I saw that it was doing some calls using the NamespaceManager to get the queue or topic.

Since this class is named **NamespaceManager**, I thought that would mean you need "**Manage**" permission anyway.
To try that, I made a basic console application using only the Azure SDK to make some calls to the NamespaceManager using a policy with only Listen or Send permissions : I got 401 errors on all the calls I tried. Adding Manage permission worked.

I didn't find anything about this assumption in the Azure documentation or maybe I missed something.

### Final question :

Is there a way to use MassTransit on Azure Service Bus with a Send or Listen policy only ? Did I miss something and I'm heading the wrong way ?

Comment: You should probably post this question on the [MassTransit project mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/masstransit-discuss)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because MassTransit is responsible for managing the topology of the service bus namespace, including creating topics and queues as well as creating and binding subscriptions, the manage permission is required.

While you might think it's a great idea to create everything in production manually and leave that permission off your application, you will always spend time figuring out why things are broken in production and frustrate your engineers. I speak from experience on this one -- it's why we require the permission.

There are also auto-delete queues created for bus management, which again requires the manage permission.

**UPDATE:** Manage is still required, however, you *might* be able to get around it. If you can create topics, queues, and subscriptions in advance, and you configure MassTransit to not create topics, queues, or subscriptions, and probably to not publish faults (unless you're going to create those topics as well), and not use error or skipped queues.

For example, this configuration would basically limit the use of MassTransit to a queue only:

```csharp
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(...);

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("existing-queue", e =>
    {
        e.PublishFaults = false;
        e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

        e.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();
        e.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();

        e.Consumer(...);
    });
});
```

Messages sent to the queue directly (destinationAddress of `queue:existing-queue`) would be consumed by the receive endpoint, and error/skipped messages would be moved to the Azure dead-letter queue. You could only call publish if the topic name matching the message type exists (or you could use `topic:existing-topic-name` as the destination address).

Comment: When I read the source code I was almost sure of that but since I'm new with MassTransit I wanted to ask it to be sure, thanks Chris for the clarification.
Since this permission is required, how would you control that a misconfigured application won't mess with a wrong queue for example ? Good Monitoring ? Do you have any ressources that talk about this point ? Thanks again for your answer !

Comment: That is a good point. Did you find any more info on this subject? I am in a situation where we need to integrate with an external software which we don't own, so I don't feel confident providing them with access key that has the manage permission.

Comment: No, didn't find or looked for more info on the subject. We use keys with "Manage" permission.

Comment: Also interested in Cedric's good question. Is this still valid for the latest version? How do people restrict permissions if an app using Masstransit is going to always be able to manage and therefore read and write any message within the namespace?

Comment: Again, you shouldn't restrict permissions unless you want to deal with operational challenges every time a new message type is created.

Comment: What if, say, we are working with a third party and they don't want to give us Manage permissions on their topics and subscriptions?

Comment: Could you add a code snippet for configuring an application that publishes (multiple types of messages) to an existing topic? I have created the topic (it's part of the application's fully automated deployment), but still the application requires manage permissions. I have not found a way to prevent MassTransit from trying to deploy (or otherwise 'manage') the topology.

Comment: To a 5 year old question? No.