# MassTransit approach when existing Azure Service Bus topics and security involved

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am implementing a library for publisher and consumers of events to communicate through Azure Service Bus and I thing MassTransit could be a good option.

I am able to work publish multiple events with it, and have several consumers receiving them without any issue if I let MassTransit create whichever topics it needs and by specifying on the consumer just a receiver endpoint for the 3 event types where I specify a queue name.

Example consumer:

```
var busControl =
    Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
        cfg =>
        {
            CreateAzureServiceBusHost(cfg, serviceBusUri, serviceBusKeyName, serviceBusKey);

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, endpoint =>
            {
                foreach (var eventDtoType in eventsTypes)
                {
                    var adapterType = typeof(EventHandlerAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(eventDtoType);
                    var resolvedType = sp.GetService(adapterType);
                    endpoint.Consumer(adapterType, type => resolvedType);
                }
            });
        });
```

*Notice that I specify as the consumer an `EventHandlerAdapterType<TEvent>` because I have an adapter to abstract the event handlers from MassTransit. But this is irrelevant for this question.*

The publisher is configured as follows:

```
var busControl =
    Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
        cfg =>
        {
            CreateAzureServiceBusHost(cfg, serviceBusUri, serviceBusKeyName, serviceBusKey);
        });
```

The problem is that I need to use this library integrated with a system that creates its own topics and it has security around it (**only certain apps can publish to it, only certain apps can read messages that have been published to that topic**)

So **I need to create a token sas for the publisher that wants to publish events on certain topics, and for the consumers who want to read from certain topics**. The creation of token is out of scope for this question though.

**MY SOLUTION ATTEMPT**:
I prepare the following scenario in Azure Service Bus:
- Create topic `topic-attempt-one` (enabled partition although not sure if relevant)
- Create a subscription `subscription-attempt-one` inside that `topic-attempt-one`
- Create a shared access policy on the topic `SamplePublishOnly` with send-only permissions
- Create a shared access policy on the topic `SampleReadOnly` with listen-only permissions

I modify my sample so that the publisher uses the key and keyName as per `SamplePublishOnly` and two consumers use the key and keyName as per `SampleReadOnly`

On the publisher, I configure it to use the **same topic** for the 3 different events.

```
var busControl =
    Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
        cfg =>
        {
            CreateAzureServiceBusHost(cfg, serviceBusUri, serviceBusKeyName, serviceBusKey);
            // Here I add the same topic name for the 3 event types I want to publish.
            cfg.Message<IEventOne>(topology =>
            {
                topology.SetEntityName("topic-attempt-one");
            });
            cfg.Message<IEventTwo>(topology =>
            {
                topology.SetEntityName("topic-attempt-one");
            });
            cfg.Message<IEventThree>(topology =>
            {
                topology.SetEntityName("topic-attempt-one");
            });
        });
```

The consumer I configure it with a receive endpoint (with one queue name for consumer one, and a different for consumer two) for the three messages with the addition of specifying exactly the topic and the subscription to use.

```
var busControl =
    Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
        cfg =>
        {
            CreateAzureServiceBusHost(cfg, serviceBusUri, serviceBusKeyName, serviceBusKey);

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, endpoint =>
            {
                //I specify the topic and subscription name that is already created in ServiceBus
                endpoint.Subscribe("topic-attempt-one", "subscription-attempt-one");
                foreach (var eventDtoType in eventsTypes)
                {
                    var adapterType = typeof(EventHandlerAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(eventDtoType);
                    var resolvedType = sp.GetService(adapterType);
                    endpoint.Consumer(adapterType, type => resolvedType);
                }
            });
        });

var busControlWrapper = new BusControlWrapper(busControl);
return busControlWrapper;
```

The consumers cannot start now the bus. There is a permission issue I think:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnauthorizedException: Manage,EntityRead claims required for this operation. TrackingId:2d6953d0-c8e1-4bdc-bed5-cc6e5d2d1f9e_G27, SystemTcker:sunnyatticsoftware.servicebus.windows.net:topic-attempt-one, Timestamp:2020-03-07T20:26:38
```

Ok so I decide to create two queues manually in Azure Service Bus for each consumers hoping that MassTransit can create virtual queues if it needs for the different messages.
- Create `queue-one`
- Create shared access policy with claims to only Listen and I call it `QueueReadOnly` and try to use its keyName and key.

Nothing. A different error but still unable to make it work

```
 Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnauthorizedException: claim is empty. TrackingId:9e344a3f-d40a-475d-bf61-7aae274ed2d1_G17, SystemTracker:sunnyatticsoftware.servicebus.windows.net:topic-attempt-one, Timestamp:2020-03-07T20:40:33
```

which kind of makes sense, because I am telling it to use a specific topic and subscription but not using the token with read permissions on them as I've replaced it with the queue one.

**QUESTIONS**

- is this the right approach for my scenario?
- is it ok to try to share the same topic for publishing 3 different message types? It seems the MassTransit design leads me to use one topic per message.
- how to achieve what I need? How do others deal with permissions if I don't want MassTransit publisher and consumers to use a `Manage` full-permission token because I don't want consumers, for example, to publish on a topic?

Thanks!

PS: I found a similar issue but unfortunately it does not solve my problem.
[How to specify which Azure Service Bus Topic to use with MassTransit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434228/how-to-specify-which-azure-service-bus-topic-to-use-with-masstransit)

**Update 1**

I found this: [Is it possible to use MassTransit 3 with Azure Service Bus without Manage permission policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096497/is-it-possible-to-use-masstransit-3-with-azure-service-bus-without-manage-permis)

which if it's still the case for the latest 6.2 version, it may explain why I'm getting those errors.
It's a pity if I can't use any claim other than 'Manage'. So, no granular permissions with Masstransit? **How would one prevent an app that has a `Manage` token from reading messaged it's not supposed to read?**
If creating entities such as topics, subscriptions or queues is not an option, is it possible to use Masstransit?

I'm guessing I lack a lot of knowledge, so any link would also be appreciated!